# Is formal truth in mathematical logic a generalization of everyday, intuitive truth?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, foundations, formal-systems

I'm trying to wrap my head around the relationship between truth in formal logic, as the value a formal expression can take on, as opposed to commonplace notions of truth.

Personal background: When I was taking a class in formal logic last semester, I found that the most efficient way to do my homework was to forget my typical notions of truth and falsehood, and simply treat truth and falsehood as formal, abstract values that formal expressions may be assigned. In other words, I treated everything formally, which from the name of the course is presumably what I was supposed to do while solving problems.

On the other hand, I came out of the course more confused than enlightened about what truth refers to in mathematics. For example, on what levels are each of the following two statements "true"?

> 1. There are infinitely many prime numbers.
> 2. The empty function $f\colon \emptyset \to \mathbb R $ is injective.

For the first one, I can obviously see that there would be a contradiction if there were only finitely many prime numbers. To me, the classic proof by contradiction is not a "formal proof" or anything; it is merely a natural language argument that proves (in the everyday sense of the word "proves") why the statement must be true (in the everyday sense of the word "true").

On the other hand, I run into trouble when I try to think about the second one. The very concept of the "empty function" doesn't even feel like it makes sense, but if I think about it as the relation between $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$ containing no elements, and then try to write out the statement formally, I get (if I did it correctly)

> $
> \forall x \forall y ( ((x\in \emptyset) \land (y\in \emptyset) \land (f (x) = f (y))) \implies (x=y))
> $

which I think has to be true in a formal sense (since the antecedent is always false?). But to be honest, I don't really know how to think about "truth" here; the situation feels much more confusing than with the first statement.

So, in conclusion, my questions are:

> In what sense is each of the above statements "true"? And, more generally,
>
> Is the notion of truth in (mathematical) logic *just* a formal value assigned to expressions? Or should I think of it as encompassing, but also generalizing, the intuitive notion of a true statement?

(Any insightful comments or answers are appreciated, even if they don't address all of my questions directly.)

Comment: They are *true* because they are theorems of "established" mathematical theories. This means that they are proved (more or less "formally" does not matter) from **axiosm** of the respective theories. Of course, they are *true* **if** the axioms are. Mathematicians usually believe that the axioms of their theories are true, unless some contradiction has been discovered.

Comment: I will bet somebody is going to comment that the "classic" (as in classical Greek culture) proof of the infinitude of prime numbers is (was) not by contradiction. I would like to add that it was not a proof of any infinitude either, because the existence of infinite collections was considered absurd at the time. Rather the proof was that any [sic] collection of prime numbers can be extended by new ones (and it was a constructive proof).

Comment: Don't confuse your confusion about truth in mathematics with your confusion about the empty function and its injectivity! These are really quite different matters. I can give an intuitive, natural language proof for (2) just as easily as for (1): To say that a function is injective is to say that no two distinct elements of the domain get sent to the same element of the codomain by the function. Since there isn't any pair of distinct elements in the domain of the empty function, this condition clearly holds, so the empty function is injective.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: What you have written only really applies to axioms of set theory (to an extent). E.g., you don't "believe" that field axioms are true. You just check when they are and when they aren't.

Comment: From one perspective, an intuitive natural-language argument is strong evidence that a purely formal proof exists. Whether or not there is a corresponding natural-language argument that feels satisfying (see e.g. user21820's answer, for instance) is up to you, but that's separate from what is true/false.

Comment: @AlexKruckman To me, vacuous truths do not make intuitive sense—in the real world, in a room where there are no cellphones, I would not claim that "all cell phones in the room are turned off" is either true or false—so the statement, "the empty function is injective," actually highlights, for me, the need for formal rules governing mathematical "truth."

Comment: @justin One can debate to what degree the meanings of logical connectives in mathematics agree with their everyday usage in natural language (I think you'll find it depends heavily on context and idiom). But these connectives have clear well-defined meanings when we're talking about mathematics, even when we're giving intuitive natural language proofs like the one you have in mind for the infinitude of the primes.

Comment: @justin And by the way, I emphatically disagree with you on the cell phone example. Vacuous truths *do* (often) make intuitive sense in non-mathematical contexts. Let's say you're on an airplane and the pilot says "For safety reasons, before we take off, all cell phones on board must be turned off". Just because it's 1995 and no one on board happens to have a cell phone doesn't mean it's any less safe to take off... the condition "all cell phones on board are turned off" for a safe take off has been satisfied - it's true!

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I think that, in everyday English, "all cell phones on board must be turned off" presupposes that there are cell-phones on board. The allowed-to-be-vacuously-true version is "*any* cell phones on board must be turned off".

Comment: @AlexKruckman +1 for the empty function proof. Actually, I think there's another example in the same spirit: under the definition of a closed set in a metric space as "a set that contains  all its limit points", $\Bbb Z$ (usual topology) is closed, since it has apparently *no* limit point at all.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "generalizing". Suppose you have total two functions $f$ and $g$ that assign truth values to closed mathematical statements.  If they agree on all inputs, neither generalizes the other. If they don't agree on some input, then they are incompatible and neither generalizes the other.  You might say that mathematical truth has a smaller domain, and so it's a specialization of the everyday notion of truth.

Comment: @AlexKruckman While we may have different intuitions, intuition is subjective, so I don't know if it makes sense to say *we* disagree—I think it's our intuitions about (and definitions of) truth that disagree. I've realized over the course of asking this question that if one wants to be purely objective, then the everyday, intuitive notion of truth is problematic precisely *because* it is intuitive—it may vary from person to person. I'm sure if I asked you to precisely enough define what you mean by "true" in the airplane example, I'd end up agreeing with you that the condition was satisfied.

Comment: Natural language is merely a vehicle for communication, and most of them are severely ambiguous to the point that a large fraction of meaning cannot be found in the spoken utterances, and even less in the written text. So while you are right that the way we interpret sentences in English, such as those involving quantifying determiners, differ slightly from person to person, our intuitive notion of truth of the **intended meaning** doesn't. That is what classical logic was invented to capture in the first place, so it ought to match our intuition about the truth value of the intended meaning.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I like to think that mathematical truth is a mathematical model of "real world truth", similar in my mind to the way in which the mathematical real number line $\mathbb{R}$ is a mathematical model of a "real world line", and similarly for many other mathematical models.

In order to achieve the level of rigor needed to do mathematics, sometimes the description of the mathematical model has formal details that perhaps do not reflect anything in particular that one sees in the real world. Oh well! That's just the way things go.

So yes, the empty function is injective. It's a formal consequence of how we axiomatize mathematical truth.

And, by the way, yes, there are infinitely many primes. The classical proof by contradiction that you feel is a natural language proof and not really a "formal proof" is actually not very hard to formalize at all. Part of the training of a mathematician is (a) to use our natural intuition, experience, or whatever, in order to come up with natural language proofs and then (b) to turn those natural language proofs into formal proofs.

Comment: Great answer. In fact, mathematical models and truth are usually addressed in introductory mathematical logic texts such as this: http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486425339

Answer (score 16):

Your main issue here seems to be that you are wondering how all the following statements:

> If the Earth is flat, then the Earth exists.
>
> If the Earth is flat, then the Earth does not exist.
>
> If there is life on Europa, then the Earth exists.

could possibly be meaningfully assigned the same truth value in the real world. These are called vacuous truths, the first two because the falsity of the condition means that the consequent is irrelevant, and the third because the truth of the consequent means that the condition is irrelevant. One could interpret logic as a game of some sort, where the prover tries to convince the refuter of his claim. If the prover makes a claim of the form:

> If A then B.

then the refuter must try to refute it. How? She must convince the prover that A is true but yet B is false. Back to our vacuous examples, the refuter must convince the prover that the Earth is flat. Nah... That's not going to happen, which is why the refuter can't refute the prover. In the third case, the refuter must convince the prover that the Earth doesn't exist. Again, no way...

On the other hand, the prover can prove the first two claims by showing that the Earth is not flat! (Come, follow me around the globe in eighty hours.) After doing this he can convince the refuter that he can always keep his promise because it can't be broken; the Earth is not flat, so the condition of his promise will never come to pass. The consequent part of his promise is irrelevant. In the third case, the condition part is immaterial because the prover can convince the refuter that no matter whether she can show that there is life on Europa, he can convince her that the Earth exists.

This is exactly the same as when you talk about an empty function being injective:

> Any function with empty domain is injective.

which expands to:
$\def\none{\varnothing}$

> Given any function $f$ such that $Dom(f) = \none$, and any $a,b \in Dom(f)$, if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$.

Well, what does the prover have to do to convince the refuter? He says, give me any function $f$ such that $Dom(f) = \none$, and give me any $a,b \in Dom(f)$! The refuter simply can't! There isn't any object in $Dom(f)$!

But wait, you say, how about the also true statement:

> Any function with singleton domain is injective.

which expands to:

> Given any function $f$ such that $Dom(f) = \{x\}$ for some $x$, and any $a,b \in Dom(f)$, if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$.

This time the refuter can continue the game. She gives the prover a function $f$ and provides an $x$ such that $Dom(f) = \{x\}$, and also gives him $a,b \in Dom(f)$. But then the prover now tells her: See? You assured me that every object in $Dom(f)$ is equal to $x$, so you've to accept that $a = x$ and $b = x$, and hence by meaning of equality $a = b$. Now I can convince you that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$. (This is exactly the third kind of vacuous statement that we discussed at the beginning.) Indeed, haven't I already convinced you that $a = b$, so you don't need to even bother to show me that $f(a) = f(b)$?

Comment: It's quiet interesting for me, that in the comments on Hurkyls answer you are taking a rather formalist approach. While here you argument with game semantics, a product of pure intuitionists. What is interesting is, that I don't feeld that this is a contradiction in this special case, while otherwise I presume formalism and intuitionism quiet far from each other. Maybe it is the favour of rigour that is common in their attitude.

Comment: @hase_olaf: What I describe here is the part that is missing in Hurkyl's answer, namely the **intuitive justification** for the rules of the formal system in use. Once the justification is done, we can then proceed entirely formally. That said, students always understand quantifiers better when explained this way, and most mathematicians too never engage in purely formal proofs, because often it is easier to grasp an argument that isn't presented in purely symbolic form.

Comment: I agree, especially with the second part. Actually I don't think ther is any proof (except of some in mathematical logic), that is written down in a purly formalistic style. So for being really exact, there is no such thing as formailsm in mathematical praxis. But somehow we know (and we are even able to achieve interpersonal konsensus about), what non-formal argument could be translated into formal ones. Do you know, if game semantics (in one or another flavour) is equivalent with classical (= aristotelic) logic? Especially: Is the law of the excluded middle part of game semantics?

Comment: @hase_olaf: That issue didn't appear in my answer (I think), but one can choose whether or not to include LEM (the law of excluded middle) in this game semantics. First note that the BHK (Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov) interpretation of proofs as programs works perfectly for intuitionistic logic, precisely because of its constructive nature. If one adds LEM then one is essentially adding some kind of oracle (it's no longer normal TMs). If you think about it that makes sense, because to get from $A \rightarrow B$ and $\neg A \rightarrow B$ to $B$ in game semantics we need to know $A \lor \neg A$.

Comment: @hase_olaf: So the game semantics actually **clarifies** what LEM means, namely that whenever the prover uses it he is asking the refuter which case it is. Is $A$ true or false? Whatever the refuter answers, he chooses the appropriate conditional branch to go down, which both intuitionistic and classical logic agree on. Intuitionistic logic thus corresponds to the refuter saying "I don't know!?" and the game gets stuck!

Comment: @hase_olaf: Secondly note that there is a perfect correspondence between perfect play in 2-player abstract games of bounded depth and quantified sentences. A first-player winning strategy begins with an existential quantifier, while a second-player winning strategy begins with a universal quantifier. Furthermore, the polynomial hierarchy is the polynomial-bounded version, relating the class of problems called QBF (Quantified Boolean Formula) and PH (polynomial hierarchy), the latter easily interpretable via games. Interestingly there is a subclass called Arthur-Merlin games using coin tosses.

Comment: Wow, I should really have made my comment a new question, so that I could accept your answer now. It is really a nice way to look at LEM. But I have to admit, your last post extends for over my knowledge. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @hase_olaf: You're welcome! The first part of my last comment should still be accessible to you, namely that whenever you play an abstract game and search $k$ moves ahead, you're really trying to figure out the truth value of some sentence with quantifier depth $k$. If you find a winning strategy it means that you have some move such that for every opponent move you have some move such that for every opponent move..., which is essentially a $Σ_k$-sentence (having $k$ alternating quantifiers beginning with $\exists$).

Answer (score 11):

Disclaimer: I am a formalist.

In my opinion, the right lesson is to question the everyday, intuitive notion of truth — i.e. I boldly assert that the everyday, intuitive notion of truth is also just a means of assigning a value to informal statements.

We like to think there is some deeper meaning to it, and there might even be such, but *in practice*, a "truth" is simply a label we put to statements that we arrive at in some sort of 'acceptable' manner, such as

- the result of a sufficiently plausible argument with accepted hypotheses
- the result of a scientific study
- the result of our brain processing external stimuli

or even things like

- deciding we are unwilling/unable to contemplate the negation
- wishful thinking

(of course, the latter two are rarely done consciously in those terms).

So the everyday, intuitive notion of truth really is similar to the formal mathematical notion of a truth valuation: it's just a means of assigning values to certain informal statements. And just as how mathematical truth valuations must respect (formal) logical deduction, we like the everyday, intuitive notion of truth to respect our various informal means of gaining knowledge.

Comment: Eh.. Your first sentence does not fairly describe you.. Most people who call themselves formalists think that mathematics is purely a game like chess where the rules are arbitrary and don't have any meaning to the real world whatsoever! You, on the other hand, are essentially saying that we adopt the rules of classical logic precisely to model what we believe our intuitive notion of real world truth satisfies, which I fully agree with. This viewpoint is quite platonic.

Comment: @user21820: Maybe I misunderstand your point, but I would say the opposite -- I try to adapt my notion of 'real world truth' to reflect lessons learned from formal logic. I try to move away from believing my knowledge reflects truths about the real world, and more towards acknowledging that the knowledge came from playing games.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point either. If you adapt your notion of real world truth based on what you learn from formal logic, it means that you indeed grant it higher ontological status than other more subjective methods of obtaining real world truth. This is precisely what the platonic viewpoint of logic means. The formalist viewpoint (aka Hilbert's) is that the games of formal systems are completely devoid of meaning and relevance to the real world. For a formalist, it matters not whether ZF is meaningful in any sense at all. All that matters is that it can produce 'elegant' theorems.

Comment: Many of them also adopt a mathematical pragmatism, namely that ZF can be used as a single axiomatic framework under which most modern mathematics can be subsumed. A formalist doesn't care whether the theorems of modern mathematics are meaningful, and sort of wants the maximum proving power, deciding between incompatible choices according to which produces more results... that's how some people justify AC over ZF. This isn't just my opinion; many formalists I've talked to literally say these things.

Comment: For what it's worth, the wikipedia article on formalism says "It is important to note that Hilbert is not considered a strict formalist as formalism is defined today. He thought there was some meaning and truth in mathematics, which is precisely why he was trying to prove the consistency of number theory. If number theory turned out to be consistent, then there had to be some sort of truth in it (Goodman, 1979). Strict formalists consider mathematics apart from its semantic meaning. They view mathematics as pure syntax: the manipulation of symbols according to certain rules."

Comment: So I retract my earlier claim that it's Hilbert's view, as I don't know what his views were after he understood Godel's results... The wikipedia article claims that "he held the opinion that there was no other meaningful mathematics whatsoever [besides finitary arithmetic], regardless of interpretation.", but no citation is given.

Comment: @user21820: I think you interpret me at the wrong level. I am not adapting what sorts of things I believe to be real world truths to make the math 'real'. Instead, I am moving in the direction of rejecting the very notion of real world truth in favor of putting the emphasis on 'knowledge-producing games'.

Comment: @user21820: Regarding mathematical reasoning, my take is that you're simply not allowed to say "... for real world reasons we have X ..." or anything similar. If you want to use X in a mathematical argument, your choices are to produce a valid formal argument concluding X or to posit X as an axiom/hypothesis. I'm not so bold as to disallow people from having outside reasons to take X as an axiom, but I insist such reasoning is not *mathematical*.

Comment: Ah then we don't disagree actually. I too share your viewpoint that we must use absolutely rigorous reasoning based on some fixed formal system. The rules and axioms for this system may have been chosen by some platonic perspectives but thereafter we have to follow them. So I'd still say that you use of "formalist" (if we go based on wikipedia) is not very accurately describing you.

Comment: Of course, if you're an intuitionist, deciding you're unwilling or unable to contemplate the negation is no reason to believe something is true...

Answer (score 7):

From a philosophical point of view this is really a big question to ask! Actually one would need a good notion of all day truth as well as of mathematical truth, to answer this question. What truth in an all-day sense could possibly mean is discussed virtually all the time throughout the history of philosophy, and I will skip this here.

The question what truth in mathematics could mean was one of the main subjects in the Foundational crisis in the early 20th century and is widly discussed ever since. The second (and highly related) question was (and is): what are the objects of mathematics? Back then there were mainly three points of view: The platonist, who thinks there are some kind of blueprints of mathematical objects and all one does, is discovering some truth (in a rather all day sense of truth) about their properties. The formalist, who does not think, mathematical objects exist at all, they are rather implicitly defined by some axioms and then truth is nothing else then consistency with these axioms. And last the intuitionist, who thinks mathematical objects are creatures of human mind. The starting point for the intuitionist is the ability to count, which amounts into the natural numbers.  Everey other object and every true statement then has to be constructed out of these first objects and some basic logic, wich does not include the law of excluded middle, i.e. no proof by contradiction. Astonishingly enough it is possible to reconstruct a quite rich part of mathematics even in a pure intuinitionist flavour.

Throughout the 20th century there were a lot of mathematical and philosohical writings around these question (see Hilbert, Brower, Whitehead, Putnam, Günther, Turing, Gödel and many others). Luckily this philosophical uncertainity didn't keep mathematicians from doing mathematics. What I think is really interesting is the capability of switching between the different states: Attacking a problem requires often (at least in my field of interest which is differntial geometry) first to get a good intuition about the objects (this is the platonist part), some strong constructive work inside the mind (this is the intuitionist part) and finally putting everything down into a rigorous proof (that is the formalist part). And most often this is not a linear process, rather a continous going forth and back...

As Reuben Hersh put it: "“The working mathematician is a Platonist on weekdays, a formalist on weekends. On weekdays, when doing mathematics, he’s a Platonist, convinced he’s dealing with an objective reality whose properties he’s trying to determine. On weekends, if challenged to give a philosophical account of this reality, it’s easiest to pretend he doesn’t believe in it. He plays formalist, and pretends mathematics is a meaningless game.... Does it matter? Yes. Truth and meaning aren’t recondite technical terms. They concern anyone who use or teaches mathematics."

If by chance you understand german: There is a really nice book of a sociologist, who did some research on how the mathematical community works and what are the main characteristics of mathematics compared to other scientific fields. It gives a good bases on some philosophical background and quiet interesting insights into the mechanics of mathematical research. Bettina Heintz: Die Innenwelt der Mathematik.

Another good question enters the game: What is the connection between mathematics and "reality"? More precicly: How does mathematics and it's applications to science, social science, engineering and so forth interact? If mathematics was just a technical game, or some construct in human mind, how is it possible, that it has such a rich field of applications? On the other hand: Do all this applications imply, that mathematical objects really live in the physical world, and if so, what does this imply for beeing able to make true statement? See for example papers of Putnam, which include deep thoughts in this direction.

Not much of an answer, more of a loos collection of some thought. Hope it gives some input though!

Answer (score 3):

Lee Mosher has already given an excellent [general answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1781791/16063), and user21820 has given a nice [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782071/16063) of vacuous truth. I'd like to expand on their answers by describing how I think about empty functions, which I find just as concrete and intuitive as other functions.

---

Like many people, I like to think of a set as a type of stuff.^ For example, there's

- a set $\mathbf{Fruit}$ which every fruit qualifies as an element of,
- a set $\mathbf{Papayas}$ which every papaya qualifies as an element of,
- a set $\mathbf{Mammals}$ which every mammal qualifies as an element of,
- a set $\mathbf{OwlPellets}$ which every owl pellet qualifies as an element of,
- a set $\{\text{Vectornaut}\}$ which only I qualify as an element of, and
- a set $\varnothing$ so exclusive that *nothing* qualifies as an element of it.

Observe that $\mathbf{Papayas} \subset \mathbf{Fruit}$, because every papaya is a fruit. Similarly, $\{\text{Vectornaut}\} \subset \mathbf{Mammals}$, because I, the only thing that qualifies as a $\{\text{Vectornaut}\}$, happen to be a mammal.

A function $A \to B$ is like a vending machine: if you drop an $A$ into the slot, the machine will spit out a $B$ for you to enjoy. If you drop in something that's not an $A$, the machine will reject it, because it only accepts $A$s. If you drop a banana into a $\mathbf{Fruit} \to \mathbf{Papayas}$ vending machine, for example, the machine will spit out a papaya. (This is a useful vending machine if you like papayas more than any other fruit.) If you drop a mouse into a $\mathbf{Fruit} \to \mathbf{Papayas}$ vending machine, the mouse will just roll out the coin return, because it's not a fruit. If you drop a mouse into a $\mathbf{Mammals} \to \mathbf{OwlPellets}$ vending machine, on the other hand, the machine will rattle around for a bit and then spit out an owl pellet. (I think I can guess what's hiding in there.)

A $\varnothing \to \mathbf{Fruit}$ vending machine is so selective that it won't accept *anything* as payment. You can dump in dolphins or owl pellets or gold dubloons, but it all just rolls out the coin return, and you never get any fruit. This is a stupid kind of vending machine, but it's useful to be able to talk about, because vending machines like this really exist—in everyday language, we call them “out of order.”

It's impossible for a $\mathbf{Fruit} \to \varnothing$ vending machine to exist. The reason is that some things really do qualify as fruit—I have one right here on my kitchen counter—and if you dropped one of those things into a $\mathbf{Fruit} \to \varnothing$ vending machine, the machine would have to spit out something that qualifies as a $\varnothing$. Since nothing qualifies as a $\varnothing$, the machine can't function as adversised.

On the other hand, it is possible for a $\varnothing \to \varnothing$ vending machine to exist. Although there's nothing the machine could give you in return for a payment, there's also nothing it will accept as a payment, so it will never fail to work as advertised.

---

^ The [rules](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543) of set theory are designed to capture this intuitive picture.

Comment: Haha! Out-of-order vending machines. Though in real life there are different instantiations of the same kind of vending machines with same input type and output behaviour, so technically the mathematical function is an abstraction of the quotient type. =)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is both, due to the quirks of formal language.  Truth is both a label assigned to expressions and also a specific concept related to your intuition.  The reason for this dichotomy is most apparent in the work of Alfred Tarksi and his [undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem).

Tarski's theorem tugs at the corners of the fabric of mathematics.  He showed that, for any theory strong enough to prove all truths in arithmetic (i.e. 1+1=2, 3*5=15, and so on) and had negation, it could not define its own semantics.  The specific statement he proved was that it could not define a function `True` such that `True(encode(s))`, where `encode(s)` was an encoded expression in that language gave the truth value for `s`.  He used a really twisted little trick known as the diagonalization lemma to basically wedge the system against itself and prove that there must be a case where the `True` function breaks down.

In many cases, we are not considering such powerful self referential systems.  Usually we're using a powerful system to prove something smaller and specific.  For example, we may use first order logic and ZF set theory to prove a statement about the cardinality of large sets.  In this sense, we are using the idea of "truth" as a label that can be applied within that system.

However, when we start exploring deeper "truths" which start to stretch the limit of our proof system, we start to find that the simple concept of "truth as a label" ceases to be as useful as it was in the simpler cases.  We start relying more on the semantic meaning of "truth" rather than the syntactic one.  Thanks to Tarski's work, we can prove that that semantic meaning *must* come from elsewhere.  It must have a deeper meaning.

This eventually does push its way into the philosophy of mathematics, where we have to define what mathematics calls "truth."  At this point, we can define "truth" any way we want, it's just a word, but there is an intuitive benefit for "truth" to have a meaning closely related to the intuitive concepts we all use.

A case study in the differences here is the difference between ZF and ZFC axioms for set theory.  The axiom of choice is a remarkably intuitive axiom, but it has profoundly non-intuitive effects.  In ZFC, it is possible to take a sphere, cut it into a finite number of pieces, rotate and translate those pieces, and reassemble them into two perfect spheres, each with the same volume as the original.  These new spheres are not swiss cheese: they are a dense sphere, just like the original one.

In ZFC, the expressions used to describe this slice and dice operaton are deemed "true," because their syntactic description is formed from a series of valid inferences in first order logic with ZFC.  However, the idea that I can double my volume of spheres without decreasing their density in any way runs so afoul of our intuitive sense of "truth" that many mathematicians refuse to accept proofs done in ZFC.

Answer (score 2):

To address your two specific questions:

1. This is true because we can demonstrate it via a proof about natural numbers. It is rather specific, since it applied to a class of very concrete objects (one could say the most concrete objects in math: "God gave us the integers, all else is the work of man." Specifically, the natural numbers probably have the most right to being "out there" in a platonic sense - we can directly observe natural numbers in the world in terms of collections of objects. Only classical geometry comes to mind as more tied to observables.
2. This question is much more "formal", since it is about matching an object to a definition. The object $f:\emptyset \to \mathbb{R}$, is both rigorously defined and yet vague as well (what does this function look like, how would I calculate it on a computer?). It is true in the sense that it satisfies the "check boxes" that define an injective function - $f$ need to correspond to anything observable or any of our everyday notions.

In general, formal methods, in fact, most "abstractions", are not inherently about anything. They consist in definitions and their verification. The extent to which they are about things beyond their own definitions is a philosophical/empirical matter. It is up to us to determine whether or not our notions concord with some formal system. If they do, then we can take advantage of the massive, extended analogical thinking that abstract/formal systems allow.

Comment: I just can't get past the claim that "there are infinitely many primes" is an empirical statement. What is the experiment that I could perform that would falsify or validate this? You say that prime numbers can be counted -- but how would one go about doing this?

Comment: @DanielWagner not literally empirical...I was trying to point out a difference but lacked a good word...hence the use of quotes. The first question is about more than just the definition of a prime number, so I was looking for a way to describe this.

Comment: @DanielWagner: It is empirical in the following sense: I can write a **concrete computer program** that given any input natural $n$ (as a string) will produce as output a natural $p > n$ such that $p$ is prime (which you can use another program to check). Why is this empirical? Because no matter what input $n$ you give this program, it will **never fail** to do as advertized. (Unless the computer runs out of memory or energy or something, in which case our claim is empirical because we can just continue on another better computer!)

Comment: @DanielWagner: Furthermore, one concrete way to do the above is to factorize every number between $n$ and $2n$ and output the first prime. Bertrand's postulate, which can be proven in PA, tells us that there will always be at least one prime in-between, and indeed that fact is empirically verifiable because this program here always halts no matter what $n$ you give it! This program not only empirically verifies Bertrand's postulate, it gives as a consequence empirical evidence that there are infinitely many primes, since if there are finitely many then there is a largest one, an upper bound.

Comment: @user21820 Except that real computers have bounded memory and speed.

Comment: @AnotherTest: We could avoid that by using an interpretation where our computer has extendable memory, such as a distributed system over the internet. Speed is another can of worms.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Experimental verification is what one might call "inductive verification" (that's **not** mathematical induction, by the way), in which you do experiments, calculations, draw pictures, test cases, and see where the evidence points. Scientists as well as mathematicians use inductive verification all the time. Computers are a fantastic tool for inductive verification, as the comments describe.

Comment: But there is another form of verification called "deductive verification", which is simply the process of crafting a formal proof. This also plays an important role in science; in mathematics, it is the final word.

Comment: @LeeMosher It seems that DanielWagner touched off a debate under my post about empirical mathematics. Unfortunately, as my response to him indicates, he misunderstood my intent. Generally, MathSE allows for precise answers since we're talking about a specific problem. But with questions like this, where everyone is air-quoting all over the place, people who are reading the posts need to be sure they understand what the posters are saying before commenting. It's too easy to talk past one another with these philosophical questions.

Comment: @LeeMosher unfortunately, it looks like the undue focus on this may have led to a downvote, perhaps the person thought I was saying we can empirically prove there are infinitely many primes...something I did not intend. I'm going to revise that statement, since it obviously does not convey what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @user21820 Extending the memory of a computer can help for a while, but when you eventually get to primes that have more binary digits than the number of atoms in the known universe, it's hard to see how you would actually build the computer to compute them. At some point before that happens, computer programming becomes more like "pure" math than a practical exercise.

Comment: @DavidK: This is going off-topic, but actually there's a big hole in your objection. Haha. If you don't think the natural numbers have some real physical meaning (not necessarily represented by particles), then you cannot think that formal systems are meaningful either. In other words, our definition of any formal system (as of today) already presupposes that strings can be indefinitely extended, otherwise there are finitely many well-formed formulae and everything in pure math just breaks down! If really the universe is finite, I don't have any idea what logic works.

Comment: @user21820 We use math as an _approximation_ to real-world phenomena all the time, so there's plenty of physical meaning to math even when the real world doesn't completely and precisely model the mathematical ideal. Does it really matter whether there are integers so large we can't store them in any computer memory in real life? Only if we insist that Peano arithmetic would then be meaningless. But it would be silly to do that.

Comment: @DavidK: I know that (did you see my message to you in a chat-room?), but I'm just saying that if PA breaks down in some fundamental way then all our meta-theorems about all logic systems also break down and we're really left with nothing of generality.

Comment: @Bey I just wanted to mention that I personally found your answer quite insightful (so I upvoted). I feel it goes along well with Hurkyl's answer to explain that formal methods are not inherently about anything, and that "truth" in general is a philosophical concept, not a mathematical one. Thus, the question of what mathematical "truth" *means* belongs to the domain of philosophy.

Comment: @justin thanks for the note. Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: @user28120: No execution of your program with finite input n will prove the point. Actual execution with infinite input will never terminate (in fact it will never start.) An experiment that has not terminated has not empirically determined its goal.

Comment: @sdenham: What are you talking about? Nobody even mentioned any infinite input. The scientific method tests a scientific hypothesis by doing experiments with **finitely** many **finite** inputs, and then concluding **empirically** whether or not the hypothesis seems to hold. It's the same I'm doing here.

Comment: @user21820 My mistake - I could not believe you were proposing something so utterly pointless.

Comment: @sdenham: No problem, sorry for not being clear enough. If only English was less vague. =)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a natural language statement you can use to verify that the empty set is injective:

> If more than one wireless device is transmitting on the same frequency, then they will interfere with each other.

Or, in other words, given $f:device\mapsto frequency$, if $f$ is not injective then you will get interference.

Naturally, when there are no devices transmitting on any frequency ($device = \emptyset$), none of them will be interfering with any of the others, and thus our empty function must be injective.

Going back to your example of "all cellphones in the room are turned off", this is just an example of implied context, since that statement wouldn't normally serve any purpose if there weren't any cellphones. However, if you add explicit context to it, like "all cellphones must be off or on airplane mode before takeoff", it should be clear that if there are no cell phones, the requirement is satisfied.

This is the reason that many mathematically-true things seem like they don't make sense in the real world: they are victims of implied context. In fact, a lot of what mathematics is for is getting rid of these implied contexts.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in some of the other answers, your question can be reformulated more concretely in terms of the natural numbers: Does $\mathbb{N}$ correspond to the ordinary (or what you call *intuitive*) counting numbers? The answer is that it depends on whether you accept the *Intended Interpretation* hypothesis, as many mathematicians do.  There is a detailed discussion of this issue [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584/looking-for-a-source-for-intended-interpretation).