# negating propositional formula with quantifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers, pumping-lemma

In order to solve an exercise in computer sciences (proving a language $L$ to not be context-free) I need to negate the Pumping-Lemma. I was provided with the definition in the following form:

If $L$ ist a a context-free language the following conditions are met:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \exists n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \forall z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \Rightarrow \exists u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*:
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \land \exists i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\in L \\
\end{alignat*}

Someone I work with provided me with a negated form which I think is not correct:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \exists z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \Rightarrow \exists u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*:
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \Rightarrow \exists i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\not\in L \\
\end{alignat*}

I myself come to the following solution:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \neg\left(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \forall z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \Rightarrow \exists u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*: \right.
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \left.{}\land \forall i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\in L \right) \\
\equiv& \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \exists z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \land \neg\left(\exists u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*: \right.
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \left.{}\land \forall i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\in L \right) \\
\equiv& \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \exists z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \land \forall u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*:
  && \neg\left(z = uvwxy \right.\\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \left.{} \land |vwx| \leq n \right) \\
 &  && \lor \neg \left(\forall i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\in L \right) \\
\equiv& \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \exists z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \land \forall u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*:
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \Rightarrow \neg \left(\forall i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\in L \right) \\
\equiv& \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+. \exists z\in L:
 |z| \geq n \land \forall u,v,w,x,y\in\Sigma^*:
  && \quad z = uvwxy \\
 &  && \land |vx| \geq 1 \\
 &  && \land |vwx| \leq n \\
 &  && \Rightarrow \exists i\in\mathbb{N}: uv^iwx^iy\not\in L
\end{alignat*}

Did I make a mistake? I cannot believe both versions are right but the source of the solution I contest I also consider quite reliable.

Thanks for any help and pointers!

Remark. *I did not post this in computer-sciences since it doesn't relate to the meaning of the Pumping-Lemma but to it's mathematical definition.*

Comment: Off-topic, but reliability in the real-world does not necessarily correspond to mathematical reliability, and technically it's irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your statement of the pumping lemma is wrong! The last quantifier should be universal.

Secondly, both of you are wrong! Next time don't write in that messy inconsistent form; either use brackets or "$:$" or "$.$" consistently. Push the negation in from the front, and systematically use De Morgan's:

> $\neg \forall x \in S\ ( \cdots ) \longrightarrow \exists x \in S\ ( \neg \cdots )$
>
> $\neg \exists x \in S\ ( \cdots ) \longrightarrow \forall x \in S\ ( \neg \cdots )$

I have no idea what you were doing once you started having unbalanced brackets. Your statement is of the form:
$\def\imp{\to}$
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$

> $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall z \in L\ ( \cdots \imp \exists u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( \cdots \land \forall i\in\nn\ ( \cdots ) ) )$

Its negation  would hence be:

> $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists z \in L\ ( \neg ( \cdots \imp \exists u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( \cdots \land \forall i\in\nn\ ( \cdots ) ) ) )$
>
> $\ \equiv \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists z \in L\ ( \cdots \land \neg \exists u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( \cdots \land \forall i\in\nn\ ( \cdots ) ) )$
>
> $\ \equiv \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists z \in L\ ( \cdots \land \forall u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( \neg ( \cdots \land \forall i\in\nn\ ( \cdots ) ) ) )$
>
> $\ \equiv \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists z \in L\ ( \cdots \land \forall u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( ( \neg \cdots \lor \neg \forall i\in\nn\ ( \cdots ) ) ) )$
>
> $\ \equiv \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists z \in L\ ( \cdots \land \forall u,..,y \in Σ^*\ ( ( \neg \cdots \lor \exists i\in\nn\ ( \neg \cdots ) ) ) )$

It's actually possible to write the negation down completely intuitively, though I recommend you **first** learn to do it mechanically. One intuitive way is via [game semantics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782071).

Comment: Yes, the quantifier was wrong -- but it was just a typo. I use '.' to delimit quantifiers and ':' after these. One can use $\neg a \lor b \equiv a \Rightarrow \neg b$ -- with this I get the same solution as you get, right>

Comment: I've edited the typo

Comment: @larkey: Ok your final answer is correct by luck, since your intermediate steps were wrong.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I made even more mistakes re-typing my draft. I hope it's correct now. But at least I know my result is right and it's not equivalent to the provided one.

Comment: @larkey: Yes I've checked your current version and it should be right. Yes the other one is wrong.