# If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(cx)=L$ for any nonzero constant $c$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I was just wondering if this proof is correct.

> I'm trying to prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ then  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(cx)=L$ for any nonzero constant $c$.

Proof:

If  $\lim_{x \to 0}f(cx)=L$ then there exists some $\delta$ such that

$0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(cx)-L|<\epsilon$. We have$ |f(cx)-L|=|f(cx)-L+f(x)-f(x)|$. Applying the triangle inequality gives

$|f(cx)-L|=|f(cx)-L+f(x)-f(x)|\leq|f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|$. So it suffices to find some $\delta$ such that

$0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Since $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=L$ there exists some $\delta_{1}$ such that

$0<|x|<\delta_{1} \implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Since this must be true for any $\epsilon>0$, it must be true for some $\epsilon>|f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|$. So, there exists some $\delta_{1}$ such that

$0<|x|<\delta_{1} \implies |f(x)-L|\leq|f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Letting $\delta=\delta_{1}$ gives the desired

$0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Please tell me if I did anything invalid. Also I'm new to Calculus so please explain as simply as possible. Thanks

Comment: You go from $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ to $\epsilon>|f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|$.  How do you do this?

Comment: "Since this must be true for any ϵ>0, it must be true for some ϵ>|f(cx)−f(x)|+|f(x)−L|" ... |f(cx) - f(x)| + |f(x)-L| is not a constant and so you can't do this.  Your proof fails from here on out.

Comment: the triangle inequality

Comment: You must separately prove that $|f(cx)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.  The triangle inequality doesn't allow you to use the same $\epsilon$ in both inequalities.

Comment: And you have to prove it for *all* epsilon.  Not merely *some* epsilon that is larger than a variable expression based on the function for all values of x.  I'm afraid your proof is simply on the wrong track.

Comment: @RossMillikan  Actually the OP wasn't trying to do the proof at that point but trying to show that it be sufficient to prove something else to prove the result.  It's actually not valid as the OP is working *from* the result and proving a *consequence* is *not* enough to prove a result.

Comment: Mis-stating the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit from the start. It should be "Since $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L$, **for every** $\epsilon  > 0$ **there exists**...

Answer (score 10):

This proof is not correct.  The key error is when you say

> Since this must be true for any $\epsilon>0$, it must be true for some $\epsilon>|f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|$.

You're trying to prove that for *every* $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(cx)-L|<\epsilon$.  So you're not allowed to choose whatever $\epsilon$ you want; $\epsilon$ is given to you ahead of time.  It is true that for any particular $x$, there exists some $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon> |f(cx)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|$.  But this isn't any use, since you don't get to choose $\epsilon$.  (Moreover, you would need this inequality to hold simultaneously for *every* $x$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$, and it is not clear how you are getting that.)

Comment: No. As Ross says in his answer, the error is at the very beginning. The proof can’t be patched if it begins by assuming what needs to be proven. The theorem to prove has the form “If *this*, then *that*.” There is no valid proof technique for this statement that begins with “If *that*...”

Comment: @SteveKass: That error is easily fixed, and is more an error of phrasing than of mathematical substance.  If you just start the proof with the sentence "So it suffices to prove that..." (and slightly rephrase the part before that to be a justification for this claim), the first part of the proof is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You start with "If $\lim_{x \to 0}f(cx)=L$", but that is what you are trying to prove.  You should start with "If $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=L$" and prove $\lim_{x \to 0}f(cx)=L.$  I like to think of $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs as challenge and response.  If you claim some limit expression, I get to challenge you with an $\epsilon$ and you have to be able to find a $\delta$ that works.  Here you are claiming $\lim_{x \to 0}f(cx)=L$, so I get to give you an $\epsilon.$  You are basing your claim on somebody else's claim that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=L$, so you get to give them an $\epsilon'$ and they have to give you a $\delta'$ that supports their claim.  The $\epsilon'$ that you choose should be derived from the $\epsilon$ that I gave you.  You take their $\delta'$ and derive the $\delta$ that you give me.

Comment: Indeed, that challenge-response model is a great model for *all* stuff with quantifiers. "For all" means "someone else gets to choose one for you" and "there exists" means "you've got to choose". And of course your goal is to make the statement come true.

Comment: @celtschk: Absolutely. And I always don't understand why it's not **taught** that way, meaning that a proof corresponds to a winning strategy for the Prover and a disproof corresponds to a winning strategy for the Refuter. This has many ties with deeper aspects of logic that so few students are aware of.

Comment: @ChrisNguyen: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782071 for an explanation of the challenge-response model that Ross mentioned.