# How does this proof by induction works?

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

> Source: [MIT OCW 6.042 by Tom Leighton, Lecture 2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-2-induction); Please skip to
>   time `1:00:45`.

In this question, the professor proves:

> $2^n.2^n$ courtyard can be filled with tiles of L shaped (composed of
>   3 unit square tiles) having a free unit square tile free for Bill at
>   the **center** is true for all $n \in N$

Failing to do so, he changes the technique to:

> $2^n.2^n$ courtyard can be filled with tiles of L shaped (composed of
>   3 unit square tiles) having a free unit square tile free for Bill at
>   the **corner** is true for all $n \in N$

But this technique cannot be extended to prove the initial proposition. So he takes a *stronger* technique:

> $2^n.2^n$ courtyard can be filled with tiles of L shaped (composed of
>   3 unit square tiles) having a free unit square tile free for Bill at
>   **any position** is true for all $n \in N$

---

I understand the idea behind taking stronger technique, and also understand the proof. I don't understand one thing.

I know that when you prove some proposition true you have to prove it for all cases. But in the above proof he fixed the positions of three blank squares, and only one is free.
[Like here blue, green and yellow are fixed and only red can be anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHXg9.png).

The total possibilities for four $4.4$ courtyards having one unit square missing, arranged in a big square of $8.8$ courtyard: $2^4.2^4.2^4.2^4 = 2^{16}$ possible layouts.

But the above proof fixes three squares so it becomes; $2^4+2^4+2^4+2^4 = 4.2^4 = 2^6$.

I'm thinking that proof like this and with this perspective it seems an incorrect proof to me. I know the proof is right, my approach is wrong, please tell me how does it work for every possibility, for example [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUWkL.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually shows that you do **not** understand induction. I very strongly advise you to learn basic first-order logic, because that is the only way to truly understand induction. However, in the interim you should read [this on induction](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550) and [this on game semantics](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782071/21820).

Once you fully understand those two posts, it should be clear what you have here:

Given **any** $2^n×2^n$ square grid with a missing unit square:
  If $n = 0$, then it is trivially tileable. So we are left with the case $n>0$.
  Thus the missing square is in one of the $4$ equal parts each of size $2^{n-1}×2^{n-1}$.
  We can remove $3$ appropriate centre squares so that each part has exactly one missing square.
  Note that those $3$ centre squares can be covered by an L-tile.
  **If** each of those $4$ parts can be L-tiled, **then** the whole grid can be L-tiled.
Therefore by induction the whole grid can be tiled.

Furthermore, the professor is incorrect that the corner version of the theorem cannot be used to prove the original proposition! Suppose you have proven the corner version. Then any square grid with size at least $2×2$ and all centre squares removed can be L-tiled (since each of the 4 parts can be L-tiled, by the corner version), and hence any square grid with size at least $2×2$ and one centre square removed can also be L-tiled.

Comment: Thanks for providing your previous posts, they are high level stuff for me. I understood a lot of it, but cannot say full of it. I'll read it again after more practice with induction. And yeah the professor said he cannot rotate the $2^n.2^n$ grid because there could be a piece such that it has two unit-squares in this grid and one in another, but it's not the case as our grids are complete themselves, thanks for verifying it too. Also please comment on my possibility deduction. Is it any logical? (Total $2^{16}$ ways and the approach in the video covers only $2^6$ possibilities thingy)

Comment: @RisingUnderDog: As I said, if you really want to understand induction you have no choice but to learn first-order logic. I did not respond to your other remarks because they are based on a faulty understanding of induction. Think slowly about induction the way I presented it in the other post. You break down an arbitrary **given** grid into smaller grids, and **if** each smaller grid can be L-tiled **then** the original grid can as well. This means that you have reduced the original problem to smaller problems. Each smaller problem in turn can be reduced in the same manner.

Comment: This reduction process is the **correct** way you should understand induction in the meantime before you learn basic first-order logic, as an interim way to get a simple but accurate grasp of induction. The reduction process eventually ends up with many tiny problems each with size $1×1$, which is the so-called base case here. The fact that it must eventually end up with only base cases is precisely the core of induction.

Comment: @RisingUnderDog: So your first step right now should be to understand the reduction process as explained in my post to the point that you are **certain** that the claim (every square grid of size $2^n×2^n$ can be L-tiled) is **true** for every natural $n$. Don't care about "induction". Just focus on the reasoning that shows that, no matter what grid you give me, I can follow the reduction process all the way to obtain an L-tiling. Once you fully get that, then let me know again and I will explain exactly what induction is doing to validate that reasoning.

Comment: Starting at about 1:12:15 the professor does realize that the 'corner' version of the proof is sufficient to then also prove the 'center' version.

Comment: @Bram28: Thanks for your comment! I did not actually watch the video and simply answered based on the question here. =)

Comment: @user21820 Yeah, it's an interesting few minutes. The professor did at first think the 'corner' version could not be used as a Lemma towards the 'center' version, but when a student pushed it the professor realizes it can. Those are always the best teaching/learning moments!

Comment: @Bram28: Indeed! That is one thing I really enjoy about teaching, namely when the student teaches me something. =)

Comment: @user21820 Hey there, sorry I was caught in some work, meanwhile I did some induction. At this point I can say that I fully understand both of your posts and the statement you mentioned. As you said, I think now you could elucidate me further on the topic.

Comment: @RisingUnderDog: Thanks for accepting my answer, and I am very glad to hear that you now understand this post. I am not free at the moment but ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161/basic-mathematics) and we shall continue at another time to discuss what exactly induction is doing here.

Comment: @user21820 Let me figure out how to ping someone there. It's my first time, I didn't know besides community forums there was a chatting system supported by stackexchange too.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a $2^{n+1}\times 2^{n+1}$ courtyard  with *any* unit square missing. Scale the courtyard down by a factor of $\frac 12$. Now you have a $2^{n}\times 2^{n}$ courtyard with *some* unit square having a defect in form of a half-unit square missing. By induction hypothesis, this $2^n\times 2^n$ courtyard can be tiled by L shapes leaving the defective unit square free. Now scale by a factor of $2$ back to the original situation. Replace the now big L shapes by four L shapes each. The defective square was scaled up to a $2\times 2$ square with the original missing unit square in one of its corners. This can be covered by a single L shape.

Comment: Thankyou I understand it now this way. Just one thing it will become one-fourth of a unit square, not half-unit square. Please also see my possibility deduction, total $2^{16}$ and the approach in the video covers $2^6$ possibilities only, please comment on that too

Comment: @RisingUnderDog With "half-unit square" I meant a square with side length half a unit. But, yes, by area it is one-fourth. - Re your other objection (Is till didn't watch the video): You miscount. As in my version but in a different, he starts with *any* arbitrary missing and reduces this to *some specific* place missing. That doesn't prevent application of the induction hypothesis that it can be done with *any* place missing